# Get notifications for pages on watchlist (MediaWiki sites)

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I've noticed that MediaWiki websites such as Wikipedia display a "you have new messages" message whenever a change is made to the user's talk page. Is it possible to get the same type of notification for pages on the user's watchlist?

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that built-in. But you could write a JavaScript script that does that.

Comment: Do you mean a GreaseMonkey userscript?

Comment: That's one possibility. But I meant something more like [user scripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_User_scripts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is soon going to be possible when the new [Echo extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aEcho) gets deployed to the English Wikipedia somewhere in March 2013. There will be a unified notification system for changes in your watchlist and your user talk pages.

Note that in a vanilla install of MediaWiki, such a feature does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an rss reader, on your [watchlist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aWatchlist), check the Atom link on the toolbox. With that, besides using an rss reader, you can also use it to feed an [user script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aWikiProject_User_scripts).